# Convert .Net ManagementBaseObject to ManagementObject

Tags: .net, wmi

I am trying to use the following code to write out all processes started on a computer.  My problem is that the EventArrived method is passed a EventArrivedEventArgs which has a NewEvent property of type ManagementBaseObject.  This does not have a InvokeMethod method.  Can I convert the NewEvent property to a ManagementObject some how, or do I need to requery and create a ManagementObject?  The code below works great, but would like to not requery.

```
Imports System.Management

Public NotInheritable Class EntryPoint

    Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)

        Dim scope As New ManagementScope("\\.\root\cimV2")
        Dim query As New WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), "TargetInstance isa ""Win32_Process""")

        Using watcher As New ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query)
            AddHandler watcher.EventArrived, AddressOf EventArrived
            watcher.Start()
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for processes to start...")
            Console.ReadLine()
            watcher.Stop()
        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs)

        Dim targetInstance As ManagementBaseObject = e.NewEvent("TargetInstance")
        Dim process As New ManagementObject("win32_process.handle=" + targetInstance("ProcessId").ToString())
        Dim output(1) As String
        process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", output)
        Console.WriteLine("Process {0} started by {2}\{1}", targetInstance("Name"), output(0), output(1))

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*IS* the object a `ManagementObject` instance? The indexer may pass the return value as a `Base` because it's a general-purpose property. Try this:

```
Private Shared Sub EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs)
    Dim targetInstance As ManagementBaseObject = e.NewEvent("TargetInstance")

    If TypeOf targetInstance Is ManagementObject Then
        Dim mo as ManagementObject = DirectCast(targetInstance, ManagementObject)
        Dim output(1) as String

        mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", output)

        Console.WriteLine("Process {0} started by {2}\{1}", targetInstance("Name"), output(0), output(1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No go... The targetInstance is not a ManagementObject instance.

Comment: In that case, no, it's not possible to do without executing another query.